# On Church numeral program under Frege

Tags: frege

This program compiles and runs correctly under GHC:

```
type Church a = (a -> a) -> a -> a

ch :: Int -> Church a
ch 0 _ = id
ch n f = f . ch (n-1) f

unch :: Church Int -> Int
unch n = n (+1) 0

suc :: Church a -> Church a
suc n f = f . n f

pre :: Church ((a -> a) -> a) -> Church a
pre n f a = n s z id
    where s g h = h (g f)
          z     = const a

main :: IO ()
main = do let seven = ch 7
              eight = suc seven
              six   = pre seven
          print (unch eight)
          print (unch six)
```

But when compiling with Frege I got the following error:

```
E /home/xgp/work/flab/src/main/frege/flab/fold.fr:23: type error in expression seven
    type is : Int
    expected: (t1→t1)→t1
E /home/xgp/work/flab/src/main/frege/flab/fold.fr:23: type error in expression seven
    type is : (t1→t1)→t1
    expected: Int
E /home/xgp/work/flab/src/main/frege/flab/fold.fr:23: type error in expression seven
    type is : (t1→t1)→t1
    expected: Int
E /home/xgp/work/flab/src/main/frege/flab/fold.fr:23: type error in
    expression seven
    type is apparently Int
    used as function
```

Why?  Is it possible to modify the program to pass the compilation under Frege?

Comment: Strange. But moving the definition of `six`, `seven` and `eight` outside of `main` to the top level and replacing `print` by `println` works.

Comment: @0dB, yes I tried moving them to the top level and the program compiled and all three values were correct.  But `print` did print something, though not that something by its own line.

Comment: Another interesting effect: When I first load the modified program (`six` at top level etc.) and in the REPL run `println (unch six)` for the first time, I get `866` (I have seen even longer numbers), the second time I get `6`. This behaviour is not consistent, though, `:reset` and doing it over sometimes directly yields `6`.

Comment: Reg. that `print` works for you (for me there is no output), maybe you and I have different Frege versions? I have 3.23.450-gf5b1730.

Comment: It sounds like that the output of the first two `print`s did not get flushed, and the final `println` flushed the output stream.

Comment: print doesn't necessarily flush, it's Java System.out.print which doesn't flush it's stream

Comment: I think types doesn't align:
why `ch` isn't Int -> Church Int?
why (pre . suc) changes type of it's parameter?

Comment: @LechGłowiak `Church a` is more general than `Church Int`. There is no reason for Church numerals to be restricted to `Int`s: a Church number `n` means, and only means, applying some function of `a -> a` to some value of `a` `n` times. The generic type parameter `a` is also the crux of allowing predecessors to be defined. Another definition of predecessor is `pre' n f a = fst (n (h f) (a, a)) where h g (_, a) = (a, f a)`, which is of type `Church (a, a)`. It also changes the type parameter. These definitions work together seamlessly, e.g. `unch $ pre' $ suc $ pre $ ch 8` will result in `7`.

Comment: Sorry, the type of `pre'` should be `Church (a, a) -> Church a`. There was no enough space to type the characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those rare cases where generalization of types of let bound variables actually does make a difference.

The point is, Frege acts like GHC with pragma `-XMonoLocalBinds` in that respect, for details see here: https://github.com/Frege/frege/wiki/GHC-Language-Options-vs.-Frege#Let-Generalization and here: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#typing-binds (there is also a link to a paper of SPJ, that explains the rationale)

What this means, in short, is that all unannotated let bound veriabes will have a *monomorphic* type, and cannot be used at different types. To restore polymorphism, an explicit type signature is needed.

To make your program compile, it is enough to annotate the binding of `seven` with

```
seven :: Church a
```

Regarding print/println: the former one does not flush the output. So you have in the REPL:

```
frege> print 'a'
IO ()
frege> print 'b'
IO ()
frege> println "dammit!"
abdammit!
IO ()
```

Comment: I had a hunch and actually played around with annotations this morning—I think I tried `do let seven = (ch 7 :: Church Int)`—, so, nice to see how it’s done right, and, good to know it’s not a bug, it’s a feature :) OK, print does not flush, that explains it (which @Lech also points out).

Comment: Well, `Church Int` is what the compiler *thinks*  should be `seven` s type (from the use of `unchr eight`) . But this doesn't play well with the function type that is expected in `pre` at this point.